# Access Cloudbees Jenkins master node

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I am very new to Cloudbees. I would like to add some external dependencies and global environment variables on the jenkins building machine. Ideally I could ssh to the building machine. Could you please tell me how. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your global env variables in Jenkins itself:

```
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Properties
```

CloudBees does not allow users to SSH to build machines or masters.